# Regex doesn't work using loop to go through filenames

Tags: regex, shell

I've been working on this for a while now and I can't seem to crack it. I have in a folder some files

```
testing.test.S09E01.720p.HDTV.x264-TWIST 
dmscript.sh
```

I have the script in there to test it before I set it up with download manager to run once an episode has been downloaded.

The script has the following code.

```
#!/bin/sh
#THIS SCRIPT WILL DETERMINE TV SHOWS AND EPISODES AND MOVE THEM TO THE CORRECT
#FOLDER WHICH WILL ALLOW EITHER SICKBEARD OR COUCHPOTATO TO RENAME AND MOVE THEM

    regex="([Ss]?([0-9]{1,2})[-|.]?[x|Ee|]?(\d{2})|(0?\d{1})(\d{2}))"

    #where the tv shows will be copied to
    tvdir="/volume1/public/NZB/Complete/tv/processed/"

    #this was a debug variable to allow me to see where the code fails
    num="1"

    #will change the * to full path of folder later, for now this works because script is running from
    #inside folder
    for filename in *
    do
            if [[ "$filename =~ $regex ]]
            then
            #display the current filename and the variable number
            echo "$filename $num"
            #commented on the following code so when the script works I will just uncomment
            #mv $filename $tvdir
            #change variable to 2, this is to see whether the if test will fail and skip the file
            #that doesn't conform to the regex
            num="2"
            else
            echo "nothing of use"

    done
```

However, once I run the code, I get this

```
testing.test.S09E01.720p.HDTV.x264-TWIST 1
dmscript.sh 2
```

obviously something goes wrong, as I just want it to display the first in the list above and ignore the other.

I got the regex rule from http://regex101.com/r/qZ2eO9/1 , I ignored the /gim at the end as I am unsure whether this will work in shell, and just stuck with the Ss and Ee so it isn't case sensitive

Comment: why not simplify and come back to complex reg-expr when everything else is working. I would do `case $f in *[Ss][0-9][Ee][0-9]* ) do stuff with $f ;; * ) echo $f didn_t match ;; esac` (or similar) . You can 'OR' (with the `|`) char multiple tests like `case $f in *[Ss][0-9][Ee][0-9]*|*[Ss][0-9][0-9][Ee][0-9][0-9]* ...`. Good luck.

Comment: I don't think that `\d` is valid in the shell like that. Try `[[:digit:]]` instead (or a class like the `[0-9]` you already used once). Also you have a typo in the snippet in the OP. You missed a quote on `"$filename`.

Comment: none of that works, when I implement the case esac, nothing appears. 'I've tried various regex combinations, nothing seems to work

Comment: Your /bin/sh probably doesn't understand regexes. Change to /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

A few modifications:

(1) fix the `\d` into `[0-9]` in the expression.

(2) fix the quotation mark `"` in the line `if [[ "$filename =~ $regex ]]`

(3) add `fi` in the end of the if block

And now the script should work.

```
regex="([Ss]?([0-9]{1,2})[-|.]?[x|Ee|]?([0-9]{2})|(0?[0-9]{1})([0-9]{2}))"

#where the tv shows will be copied to
tvdir="/volume1/public/NZB/Complete/tv/processed/"

#this was a debug variable to allow me to see where the code fails
num="1"

#will change the * to full path of folder later, for now this works because script is running from
#inside folder
for filename in *
do  
        if [[ $filename =~ $regex ]]
        then
            #display the current filename and the variable number
            echo "$filename $num"
            #commented on the following code so when the script works I will just uncomment
            #mv $filename $tvdir
            #change variable to 2, this is to see whether the if test will fail and skip the file
            #that doesn't conform to the regex
            num="2"
        else
            echo "nothing of use"
        fi  
done
```